# Setting animationImages array with UIImage's retrieved from Core Data store causes crash?

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios4, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I cant locate in apple docs nor scanning the web for the solution to this problem.

I retrieve images (all ~70KB) from Core Data store using a fetch request with sort descriptor, make a mutable copy of the result and add the objects to a mutable array as follows...

```
NSFetchRequest *requestA = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YearPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[requestA setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[requestA setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];



NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResultsA = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestA error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResultsA == nil) {

}

[self setImageArray:mutableFetchResultsA];
[mutableFetchResultsA release];
[requestA release];
```

I then setAnimationImages to this mutable array......

```
 self.theImageView.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
```

I have checked using

```
NSLog(@"array's content:%@",imageArray);
```

Which confirms the array is not (null), I get multiple examples of below as expected....

```
"<YearPhoto: 0x16d0e0> (entity: YearPhoto; id: 0x16bc10 <x-coredata://2F4DDE20-855E-484A-AC8F-9F8E60F4162E/YearPhoto/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
```

When the app crashes, it faults on this line of code..

```
    self.theImageView.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:imageArray];
```

Debugger throws out...

```
2011-08-03 15:53:24.843 Year_book_app[2773:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[YearPhoto scale]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x190d60'
```

I have no idea why it fails. Can anyone shed any light on the matter. Am I seeding the animation images correctly?

I thank you in advance of any help!!

If you need any further details, please let me know.

DetartrateD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is you are sending objects that are type of `YearPhoto` instead of `UIImage`. `self.theImageView.animationImages` takes an array of UIImages as a valid value.

Comment: your eyes work better then mine it appears, I cant believe I missed that!!! I thank you for pointing out the obvious, sometimes you spend too long looking and cant see the wood for the trees!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer ur vote it up if you think it helped! Cheers!